# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x42ff4005 (code=2), thread 8285

Tags: java, android, c++

I am trying to use some c++ function with JNI to run on an Android app.

Here is my native function in NativeLib.java:

```
private static native void drawHog(long img, long output, long decriptor, double width, double height, 
        double width2, double height2, int scalar, double fz_factor) ;
```

This is my .h generated by javah:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_example_test_NativeLib */

#ifndef _Included_com_example_test_NativeLib
#define _Included_com_example_test_NativeLib
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_test_NativeLib_drawHog
(JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong, jlong, jlong, jdouble, jdouble, jdouble, jdouble, jint, jdouble);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

here is NativLib.cpp

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "com_example_test_NativeLib.h"

using namespace cv;

Mat get_hogdescriptor_visual_image(Mat& origImg,
                               vector<float>& descriptorValues,
                               Size winSize,
                               Size cellSize,
                               int scaleFactor,
                               double viz_factor);//function to draw something, defined later
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_test_NativeLib_drawHog
(JNIEnv * env, jclass obj, jlong img_l, jlong outimg,jlong dec_l, jdouble _winw, jdouble _winh,
      jdouble _cellw, jdouble _cellh, jint scalar, jdouble fac)
{
Mat& orgimage = *(Mat*)img_l;
Mat& out = *(Mat*)outimg;
vector<float>&  descriptorValues = *(vector<float>*)dec_l;
Size winSize(_winw,_winh);
Size cellSize(_cellw, _cellh);
out = get_hogdescriptor_visual_image(orgimage,descriptorValues,winSize,cellSize,
        scalar,fac);
}
Mat get_hogdescriptor_visual_image(Mat& origImg,
                               vector<float>& descriptorValues,
                               Size winSize,
                               Size cellSize,
                               int scaleFactor,
                               double viz_factor)
{
     // do some thing.....
}
```

when the program is running, it says :

```
07-08 14:45:40.947: D/dalvikvm(8445): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.test-1/libNativeLib.so 0x41e4b868
07-08 14:45:40.947: D/dalvikvm(8445): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.example.test-1/libNativeLib.so 0x41e4b868
07-08 14:45:40.947: D/dalvikvm(8445): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.example.test-1/libNativeLib.so 0x41e4b868, skipping init
07-08 14:45:41.347: A/libc(8445): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x42ff4005 (code=2), thread 8445 (om.example.test)
```

I added some trys to see the problem in NativeLib.java

```
        try {
        drawHog(img.getNativeObjAddr(),outputMat.getNativeObjAddr(),descriptor.getNativeObjAddr(),winSize.width,winSize.height,
                cellSize.width,cellSize.height,_scalar,_fz_factor);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
```

However, there is no print out for this tracktrace.... When I try to debug it as a Native Application, I have the following error report:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2j9pss09aa58puf/QQ%E6%88%AA%E5%9B%BE20140709155652.png

But I checked the parameters in the function, none of them is null.

Comment: At an admittedly quick look, you seem to be trying to dereference a jlong as a pointer; that's pretty suspect, though theoretically workable if you have initialized the value to a legitimate memory address before calling the function.  Please show how you are invoking the function with a proper memory address there, and the actual native stack trace of the crash.

Comment: Question is updated... You may be interested.

Comment: Native stack traces will not pass back to Java as Exceptions, rather they will be found in the device log (ie, logcat tool).  Your invalid access is not at 0 (typical system value of "null") but rather at 0x42ff4005.  That in and of itself is a very suspicious looking address, since being not even half-word aligned it's unlikely to be a valid place for a structure/object to start (especially if this is an ARM device where unaligned word access is prohibited).  You should probably log the addresses passed to your native function as longs.